# JS функция Data

Tags: javascript

есть json

```js
var json = [
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-10 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"2","data":"2019-03-11 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 00:00:00"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:29"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:30"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:40"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:57:45"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:01"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:10"},
  {"value":"1","data":"2019-03-12 18:58:22"}
];
console.log(json);
```

нужна поле data сделать функцию чтобы поле data перевести
в js data  с помощью `new Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json = json.map(el => {return { value: el.value, data: new Date(el.data) }; });
```